# Api connectors not working [Before creating the user]

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have tried to use api connectors in sign-up flow, But it's not working.

[image]

**I have tried following**

(1) Api Connectors registration :

[image]

(2) Linked api connectors in sign-up flow (Before creating the user)

[image]

(3) End point (API)

** I am not using parameter values in api, returning static status result. Just for testing purpose.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            Task<string> body = stream.ReadToEndAsync();

            return new BadRequestObjectResult(
            new ResponseContent("ShowBlockPage", "You are blocked by authority"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected, you’re returning a bad request HTTP code, without a properly formed response to show the friendly error.

Here is an example error response:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/relying-party-rbac/source-code/AADB2C.RBAC.Sample/AADB2C.RBAC.Sample/Controllers/IdentityController.cs#L34

Carefully examine the b2crsponsemodel model and mimic its behaviour.

More info here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message

Comment: The link appears to be outdated as it results in 404. Facing the similar issue where api is responding with correct output as shown in the documentation, but ShowBlockPage is not working. 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": "ShowBlockPage",
    "userMessage": "There was a problem with your request. You are not able to sign up at this time.",
}